# Regex for valid URI Java

Tags: java, regex, validation, uri

I have the following task: I must make a regex for valid URI in these syntax: 
`scheme:[//[user[:password]@]host[:port]][/path][?query][#fragment]`  . And the symbols ":","/", "?","#","[]", "@" must be saved (maybe it means constants) and if they are used like a part of some component(path,query,fragment) they must be percent-encoded (instead question mark must be - %3F).

Could you please help me about that regex. Here is mine for now, but i'm not sure is it correct:

> ```
> ([.//ftp]+[://a-z.]+[@.a-z?0-9:]+[://a-zA-Z0-9]+[&?a-z=#0-9]+)
> ```

Here are some valid examples:

```
ftp://myusername:mypassword@localhost:21/somepath/somepath?key=value#somefragment
ftp://myusername:mypassword@localhost:21/somepath?key=value#somefragment
ftp://myusername:mypassword@localhost:21?key=value#somefragment
ftp://myusername:mypassword@localhost:21#somefragment
ftp://myusername:mypassword@localhost:21

ftp://myusername:mypassword@localhost/somepath/somepath?key=value#somefragment
ftp://myusername:mypassword@localhost/somepath?key=value#somefragment
ftp://myusername:mypassword@localhost?key=value#somefragment
ftp://myusername:mypassword@localhost#somefragment
ftp://myusername:mypassword@localhost

ftp://myusername@localhost/somepath/somepath?key=value#somefragment
ftp://myusername@localhost/somepath?key=value#somefragment
ftp://myusername@localhost?key=value#somefragment
ftp://myusername@localhost#somefragment
ftp://myusername@localhost

ftp://localhost/somepath/somepath?key=value#somefragment
ftp://localhost/somepath?key=value#somefragment
ftp://localhost?key=value#somefragment
ftp://localhost#somefragment
ftp://localhost


ftp://myusername:mypassword@localhost:21/somepath/somepath?key=value#somefragment
ftp://myusername:mypassword@localhost:21/somepath?key=value&abc=xyz#somefragment
ftp://myusername:mypassword@localhost:21?key=value&abc=xyz#somefragment

ftp://myusername:mypassword@localhost/somepath/somepath?key=value&abc=xyz#somefragment
ftp://myusername:mypassword@localhost/somepath?key=value&abc=xyz#somefragment
ftp://myusername:mypassword@localhost?key=value&abc=xyz#somefragment

ftp://myusername@localhost/somepath/somepath?key=value&abc=xyz#somefragment
ftp://myusername@localhost/somepath?key=value&abc=xyz#somefragment
ftp://myusername@localhost?key=value&abc=xyz#somefragment

ftp://localhost/somepath/somepath?key=value&abc=xyz#somefragment
ftp://localhost/somepath?key=value&abc=xyz#somefragment
ftp://localhost?key=value&abc=xyz#somefragment

../../../resource.txt

//myusername:mypassword@localhost:21/somepath/somepath?key=value#somefragment
//myusername:mypassword@localhost:21/somepath?key=value#somefragment
//myusername:mypassword@localhost:21?key=value#somefragment
//myusername:mypassword@localhost:21#somefragment
//myusername:mypassword@localhost:21

//myusername:mypassword@localhost/somepath/somepath?key=value#somefragment
//myusername:mypassword@localhost/somepath?key=value#somefragment
//myusername:mypassword@localhost?key=value#somefragment
//myusername:mypassword@localhost#somefragment
//myusername:mypassword@localhost

//myusername@localhost/somepath/somepath?key=value#somefragment
//myusername@localhost/somepath?key=value#somefragment
//myusername@localhost?key=value#somefragment
//myusername@localhost#somefragment
//myusername@localhost

//localhost/somepath/somepath?key=value#somefragment
//localhost/somepath?key=value#somefragment
//localhost?key=value#somefragment
//localhost#somefragment
//localhost


//myusername:mypassword@localhost:21/somepath/somepath?key=value#somefragment
//myusername:mypassword@localhost:21/somepath?key=value&abc=xyz#somefragment
//myusername:mypassword@localhost:21?key=value&abc=xyz#somefragment

//myusername:mypassword@localhost/somepath/somepath?key=value&abc=xyz#somefragment
//myusername:mypassword@localhost/somepath?key=value&abc=xyz#somefragment
//myusername:mypassword@localhost?key=value&abc=xyz#somefragment

//myusername@localhost/somepath/somepath?key=value&abc=xyz#somefragment
//myusername@localhost/somepath?key=value&abc=xyz#somefragment
//myusername@localhost?key=value&abc=xyz#somefragment

//localhost/somepath/somepath?key=value&abc=xyz#somefragment
//localhost/somepath?key=value&abc=xyz#somefragment
//localhost?key=value&abc=xyz#somefragment



ftp://myusername:mypassword@localhost.com:21/somepath/somepath?key=value#somefragment
ftp://myusername:mypassword@localhost.com:21/somepath?key=value#somefragment
ftp://myusername:mypassword@localhost.com:21?key=value#somefragment
ftp://myusername:mypassword@localhost.com:21#somefragment
ftp://myusername:mypassword@localhost.com:21

ftp://myusername:mypassword@localhost.com/somepath/somepath?key=value#somefragment
ftp://myusername:mypassword@localhost.com/somepath?key=value#somefragment
ftp://myusername:mypassword@localhost.com?key=value#somefragment
ftp://myusername:mypassword@localhost.com#somefragment
ftp://myusername:mypassword@localhost.com

ftp://myusername@localhost.com/somepath/somepath?key=value#somefragment
ftp://myusername@localhost.com/somepath?key=value#somefragment
ftp://myusername@localhost.com?key=value#somefragment
ftp://myusername@localhost.com#somefragment
ftp://myusername@localhost.com

ftp://localhost.com/somepath/somepath?key=value#somefragment
ftp://localhost.com/somepath?key=value#somefragment
ftp://localhost.com?key=value#somefragment
```

Comment: Is this for a homework assignment?  Note that the `java.net.URI` package already has methods which can parse URLs/URIs.

Comment: Did you test against known valid and invalid examples? As an example: what do you think `[@.a-z?0-9:]+` should match and what shouldn't it match? Should it match `@.@1234@` for example?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen - yeah i must do it with a regex that is my task

Comment: As @Thomas mentioned, your current regex is a bit weird.. The part `[.//ftp]+` for example also matches `t/fppt` or `/////////` or `.fptpfpt././.`. The `[...]+` basically means: "_match any of these characters (including potential duplicates), one or more times_". You should use a combination of `(...)+` and `[...]`. The `a-z` should be placed inside `[]`-blocks, but the `ftp` should not.

Comment: " i must do it with a regex that is my task" - then I'd assume the goal is for you to learn regex. Did you grab a tutorial on that?

Comment: yep i did but actually i cant get the idea for it

Comment: @George What are some of the parts you don't understand of the tutorial you've used? (And which tutorial did you use?)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/ This tutorial i read.

Comment: Did you read all of it?  Did you read what a character class is?  The start of https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html explains that `[abc]` means “a, b, ***or*** c.”

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to write roughly its matching RegEx. It seems working but of course there may be lacks! I'm not a RegEx guru.

```
[ftp:]*\/\/([a-z0-9]+[\:]*[a-z0-9]+[a-z0-9]*)[@]*([\\.a-z0-9]+)([0-9a-zAz:]+)[\/?#]*([\\.\/a-z0-9]+)?([?=]([^#]*))?[#a-zA-Z]*
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0jIfwH/2) (without `../../../resource.txt`)

---

Added catch of `../../../resource.txt`. I again warn that there may be lacks!

```
([ftp:]|[\.\.])*\/[\/]{0,1}([a-z0-9\.\/]*[a-z0-9]*)([\\.a-z0-9]+)([0-9a-zAz:]+)[@]*[\/?#]*([\\.\/a-z0-9:]+)?([?=]([^#]*))?[#a-zA-Z]*
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TgVP2b/1)

The answer is open for any editing and quotation!

Comment: Yeah it is good , but the only thing it doesnt match is : ../../../resource.txt

Comment: @George humm, yes, it is an example of meaning of _lack_. I'll try to catch it which is not easy though in this context

Comment: @George I think early for accepting my answer. There are gurus for regex like Tim Biegeleisen, anubhava(Anubhava Srivastava) and mores who can answer very much better.